# How to connect a table from azure sql database to Easy Tables's table?

Tags: android, database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

How can I view a table from azure sql database in Easy Tables so I can view that on android app? 
Already configured the App Service (mobile app) and if I create a table in Easy Tables I can view that on my app. 
But if I create the same table in azure sql database and add the table to Easy Tables I only get the column's name without records.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, if you use Easy Tables, you need to Add tables via Azure Portal, then Azure would automatically create the Node.js backend for your table and provide the table endpoint API for communicating with your table. I tried to connect my Azure sql database via SSMS and a new table named `Tag`, then I add it to Easy Tables via Azure Portal.

You could check the created Node.js backend via access the "DEVELOPMENT TOOLS > App Service Editor (Preview)" section of your Mobile App as follows:

[image]

> But if I create the same table in azure sql database and add the table to Easy Tables I only get the column's name without records.

You could follow the approaches below for checking your records:

- In general, you could access "MOBILE > Easy tables" of your Mobile App, then click the table from the list, then you could view the records.
- Use the [http table interface of Easy tables](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-13-the-http-table-interface/) via the browser to check the records as follows:

  [image]
- You could leverage the client tool (e.g. [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/)) to connect with your Azure sql database, then check the table records.

If you could retrieve the records via the above approaches, then for your mobile client you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library) to check your code. If your mobile client could not retrieve the records while your table has the records, I assume that you could leverage [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces when you executing the query against your backend table. If all the above trials could not solve your problem, you need to update your question with the related client code for us to narrow this issue.